# How to update the GPS location for every 10 secs?

Tags: java, android, updates

I have these variables and have the following call in the onResume method:

```
  private Location userLocation;
  private GeoPoint point;
  private LocationManager manager;
  private LocationListener listener = new LocationListenerC();

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 25, locationListener);
```

but when I run this app in the android emulator, the location of the user is not updating every 10 secs. Can anyone help?

Comment: FYI updating every 10 seconds is going to *destroy* people's battery life...

Comment: Is it getting updated at all?? or just issue with 10 sec

Comment: he is just keeping android-style, it's ok

Comment: Did you try to change location within 10 seconds in emulator? I think, if location was not changed then it will not update..

Comment: The location is updating when its 25m

Answer (score 2):

The parameter `mindTime` doesn't mean you are going to receive updates **every** `minTime` milliseconds. It means you won't receive updates too often as less than `minTime` milliseconds, but doesn't specify **when** you will get them. If the `LocationManager` has no new location to give you every 10 seconds, it simply won't give. You will only receive an update when there's a new location.

You are using `minDistance` too. `25` means you won't receives new updates unless the device has moved at least 25 meters. The emulator doesn't move, so set this parameter to be `0` (Which means updates do not depend on whether the user has moved or not).

The updates rate depends a lot on the user location. If, for example, the user is inside a building, it may take a while for the GPS/Network providers to receive updates from the satellites/base stations. So you may be getting updates in longer intervals. However, if the user is outside and the device has good signal, updates may become extremely frequent (But you will get only 1 in every 10 seconds)

If you want to get a location every 10 seconds, you can call `getLastKnownLocation` every 10 seconds. Location may be the same though, if no updates from the providers have occured.

Comment: how can i call getLastKnownLocation every 10 secs?

Comment: @user1850173 I think you can use Timer.
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Answer (score 0):

I think, 
The condition must be, time is 10(minimum) seconds AND distance is 25(minimum) meters.

ref:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29

The minDistance parameter can also be used to control the frequency of location updates. If it is greater than 0 then the location provider will only send your application an update when the location has changed by at least minDistance meters, AND at least minTime milliseconds have passed. However it is more difficult for location providers to save power using the minDistance parameter, so minTime should be the primary tool to conserving battery life.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following,as below

```
   private Location userLocation;
   private GeoPoint point;
   private LocationManager manager;
   private LocationListener listener = new LocationListenerC();

    //Change **locationManager** to **manager** 
    // and **locationListener** to **listener**  in the follwing line
   manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 25, listener);
```